# Passing variables to a container on startup

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, deployment

I want to setup my Django app in kubernetes environment in such a way that while creating the app container, environment variables are passed such that those environment variables are used to initiate the containers. For example on starting the app container I want to issue management commands such as

```
python manage.py createuser --lastname lname --firstname --fname --number --num "
```

and so on. How to pass these variable values such as lname and fname above inside the container in a generic way such that every time new values can be passed depending on the user credentials and they do not need to be hard coded everytime?

Comment: You should be able to do this as a script that runs as container startup time, possibly an entrypoint wrapper script.  What have you already tried?  (Outside of Docker, could you write a script that did what you wanted and then launched the Django application?)

Comment: yes i run a shell script that quries the database pod as:         kubectl exec -it database-pod -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"Select json_build_object('first_name',first_name,'last_name',last_name,'email',email,'date_joined',date_joined)

Comment: I want to use the values returned by this shell script to initialize the container such as lastname etc

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container) in your deployment manifest, for example:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

You [can also invoke them in container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config) by using `command` and `argument` object, the same way as running a command in container

```
  containers:
  - name: env-print-demo
    image: bash
    env:
    - name: GREETING
      value: "Warm greetings to"
    - name: HONORIFIC
      value: "The Most Honorable"
    - name: NAME
      value: "Kubernetes"
    command: ["echo"]
    args: ["$(GREETING) $(HONORIFIC) $(NAME)"]
```

It is also possible to pass variables from [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) or [`Secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-a-container-environment-variable-with-data-from-a-single-secret).

Comment: In my case i do not know the environment variables beforehand. The values need to be set as result of a bash script that gets values from querying a database pod. How to set the environment variable values dynamically?